# use maptools::sunriset() inside mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, r-maptools

I'm trying to use `dplyr` to calculate sunrise time for a set of lon/lat/timestamp coordinates, using the `sunriset` function from maptools. Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(maptools)
library(dplyr)

pts <- tbl_df(data.frame(
  lon=c(12.08752,12.08748,12.08754,12.08760,12.08746,12.08748),
  lat=c(52.11760,52.11760,52.11747,52.11755,52.11778,52.11753),
  timestamp=as.POSIXct(
    c("2011-08-12 02:00:56 UTC","2011-08-12 02:20:22 UTC",
      "2011-08-12 02:40:15 UTC","2011-08-12 03:00:29 UTC",
      "2011-08-12 03:20:26 UTC","2011-08-12 03:40:30 UTC"))
))

pts %>% mutate(sunrise=sunriset(as.matrix(lon,lat),
                                timestamp,POSIXct.out=T,
                                direction='sunrise')$time)
```

When I run this code, I get the error

> "Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'"

I'm guessing this means that I'm not passing the variables into `sunriset` correctly.

This method does work, if I do it without `dplyr`

```
pts$sunrise<-sunriset(as.matrix(select(pts,lon,lat)), 
                    pts$timestamp, POSIXct.out=T, 
                    direction='sunrise')$time
```

However, I have lots of rows (around 65 million) and the above method is really slow even with a small fraction of that. I'm hoping that dplyr will be faster. If anybody has other suggestions on what method might be fastest, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: You could try the following with data.table. `setDT(pts)[,sunrise := sunriset(matrix(c(lon, lat), ncol = 2, nrow = 6, byrow = FALSE), timestamp, POSIXct.out=T, direction='sunrise')[2]][]`

Comment: the matrix copy (+ the fact that `sunriset` is not C/C++-backed) is prbly the thing taking the time tho @jazzurro (i expanded my answer).

Comment: @hrbrmstr I see. In that case, using dplyr or data.table would not speed up the process that much then. Thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sunr <- function(lon, lat, ts, dir='sunrise') {
  # can also do matrix(c(pts$lon, pts$lat), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) vs 
  # as.matrix(data.frame…
  sunriset(as.matrix(data.frame(lon, lat)), ts, POSIXct.out=TRUE, direction=dir)$time
}

pts %>% mutate(sunrise = sunr(lon, lat, timestamp))
```

is one way to handle it (and has the side-effect of cleaner `mutate` pipelines) but I'm not sure why you think it will be faster. Either way, the bottleneck is (most likely) the creation of the matrix for the call to `sunriset` which is going to happen either way.

The `maptools` source is pretty easy to go through and has a non-exported function `maptools:::.sunrisetUTC()` that does:

```
".sunrisetUTC" <- function(jd, lon, lat, direction=c("sunrise", "sunset")) {
## Value: Numeric, UTC time of sunrise or sunset, in minutes from zero
## Z.
## --------------------------------------------------------------------
## Arguments: jd=julian day (real);
## lon=lat=longitude and latitude, respectively, of the observer in
## degrees;
## sunrise=logical indicating whether sunrise or sunset UTC should be
## returned.
```

You could try doing passing in the julian day, lon, lat & direction to it vs the exported functions to avoid the data copying. However, if performance is critical, I'd use `Rcpp` to write an inline, vectorized C/C++ function based on [this](http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_example.htm).

Comment: hrbrmstr, thank you for the information. so far my use has been one-off and I've been able to live with the performance issue. I'll try out your suggestions in case I need to have fast performance on a consistent basis.  

In case anbody else reads this, I happened upon this code: http://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/sunriset.c 

It appears to be an implementation of the sunriset function in c